# How to handle "provided autowired" beans in a Spring-based Java library

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, autowired

We have a Spring-based Java **library**. There is a code like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {
    @Bean
    public MyClass createMyClass(@Autowired ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The code is supposed to be used only as a library, as part of a full Spring Boot application. In that application, there is ensured that an `ObjectMapper` bean always exists.

Maven build ends up with BUILD SUCCESS. However, IntelliJ IDEA complains:

```text
Could not autowire. No beans of 'ObjectMapper' type found.
```

[image]

What is the correct way of solving the issue?

1. Is there an annotation parameter something *like* `@Autowired(provided=true)` telling the IntelliJ that the bean will be provided in the full program?
2. Is it OK just to ignore / suppress (and how?) this IntelliJ error, secretly knowing that it will be eventually OK?
3. Or is it a bad practice and such code should be avoided and replaced by another construct?

EDIT:

As a solution I tried to add to the library a "fake" bean like this:

```java
@Bean
@OnMissingBean
public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}
```

This made IDEA happy, however as Spring Boot creates the bean *also* with `@OnMissingBean` annotation (or maybe it wasn't `ObjectMapper` but some other class, it doesn't matter now), I never knew which bean takes precedence and it happened that *this* fake bean was used.

Comment: What do you mean by "IntelliJ IDEA complains"? Is this a warning while building the project or a tooltip visible when you hover `ObjectMapper`?

Comment: @JoãoDias It is a tooltip, but it is also an UGLY RED underlined code :( Which attracts my attention, and I am learning to ignore alerts :(

Comment: May you share a sample project? Could be IDEA bug. Worth reporting to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Comment: Ignore it. Or make sure you have setup uyour spring boot app as such and the proper contexts in intellij. Or disbable the spring highlighting.

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov For the sample project, just create a library without any Spring Boot starter and place there a class like my class from the example. I do not think it is a *bug*, **IDEA is right** that there is no eligible bean available. I have rather a *doubt* how to handle it properly.

Comment: @M.Deinum I was wandering whether there is a "pattern" how to write Spring libraries properly. I added to my question a solution I tried, with an explanation why it did not work.

Comment: You can disable the inspection for the scope: Alt+Enter + Right Arrow > suppress an inspection in a given scope

Comment: @KonstantinAnnikov Is it OK to suppress the inspection? Isn't the warning rather trying to hint me that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: If your application is running, there is nothing wrong. Intellij without fully setting up the context doesn't know what is available, it is a hint not an error. Your solution isn't a solution it is only to make the IDE happy.